# Merging two objects into one array

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to put two objects into one array to loop through.

```
    $arr = array();
    while ($data = $d->fetch()) {
        $a = new aEntity();
        $b = new bEntity();
        $a->setData1($data['data1']);
        $b->setData2($data['data2']);
        $arr[] = (object) array_merge((array) $a, (array) $b);
    }
    return $arr;
```

How do I put the values of `$a` and `$b` into `$arr[]`?

Using `array_merge()` throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 28672 bytes)

Thank you for your help

Comment: What are `$a` and `$b`? What are you showing us in the first piece of code?

Comment: Removed the first piece of code for clarity. $a and $b are the two objects I'm trying to merge @Dharman

Comment: Sounds to me like you are just running out of memory. How big are these data structures? What else is going on in the script that is using memory

Comment: What is the content of $d. Running out of memory happens often, when a while-loop never stops. At first I would var_dump($d) to be shure, the loop comes to an end.

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to convert objects to arrays is to first encode the object into JSON, and then decode them using the array flag. (See [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

```
$new_array = array();
if (is_array($arr) || is_object($arr)) {
    foreach($arr as $d) {
        $d = json_encode($d); //this will convert an object OR an array to JSON
        $d = json_decode($d,TRUE); 
        //the TRUE flag will convert JSON to an array rather than an object
        $new_array = array_merge($d,$new_array);
        //merges array $d into $new_array
    }
}
```

`$new_array` will be an array containing the elements both objects.